# number of strictly increasing sequences of length $K$ with elements from $\{1, 2,\cdots,N\}$?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, computational-complexity

What is the number of strictly incremental sequences of length $K$ with elements from $\{1, 2,\cdots,N\}$ ?

Is there any exact value? How about approximations?

Comment: Can we use the same number several times ?

Comment: @Traklon. No! Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Take all subsets of size $K$ from $\{1,2,\ldots,N\}$. There are ${N \choose K}$ such subsets. Each such subset can be arranged to form exactly one strictly increasing sequence. Therefore, there are ${N \choose K}$ such sequences.

Comment: Sorry. I must edit my question! This is not what I am looking for. What should I do? Post a new question?

Comment: Well, it depends on how different your question is. If it is quite different, I suggest you open a new question.

Comment: What if K=0? What does it mean to say that there is 1 strictly increasing subsequence of length 0?

Comment: Any way to find number of sequences not strictly increasing, ie. non-decreasing sequences?

Answer (score 3):

OK, so if we can't use the same number twice, I think there is a simple approach : just take $K$ elements from the set.
Starting from here, sort the $K$ elements : you have a strictly incremental sequence.
Furthermore, a strictly incremental sequence may only come from one given set.
So there is a bijection between the number of strictly incremental sequences, and the number of sets.

So the answer is $\frac{N!}{K!*(N-K)!} = $ $N \choose K$.

Comment: In closed form, note that your answer is ${N \choose K}$.

Comment: I just didn't know how to write it in Tex ! Thanks ! x)