# There are n balls in a jar labeled with 1,2,...,n. A total of k balls are drawn with replacement. What is the probability of a nondecreasing sequence?

Tags: probability, combinatorics

This comes from Stat 110 Blitzstein book. There are no solutions so I wanted to see if my solution is correct.

There is another post ([There are n balls in a jar labeled with numbers 1,2,...,n. A total of k balls are drawn WITH REPLACEMENT.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2896881/there-are-n-balls-in-a-jar-labeled-with-numbers-1-2-n-a-total-of-k-balls-ar)) dedicated to strictly increasing, where the answer is seen to be $n \choose k$ / $n^k$.

I wanted to approach this nondecreasing problem similarly, so I used the fact that for any set of k numbers, there is exactly one way to order them in a nondecreasing manner. So, we can transform this problem into how many unique unordered sets of $k$ can we get from $n$ possibilities.

I thought this might be solved using stars and bars, where there are initially there are $n$ different locations, and we add have to place $k$ bars, giving us a solution of:

${n + k -1} \choose {k}$$ / n^k$.

Could someone help verify or discredit this? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your answer is correct

Consider the $n$ jars as $n$ bins, and the $k$ balls withdrawn as $k$ balls put in to make it a direct stars and balls format problem.

Then the *total* number of ways possible is $\;\;\Large\binom{k+n-1}{k}$

and since the jars/bins are labeled $1$ to $n$, *all* such selections will necessarily be in non-decreasing  order. (Note that although each selection by stars and bars will not have the same probability, here we are simply counting *all* selections)

$$Pr = \dfrac{\dbinom{k+n-1}{k}}{n^k}$$

Comment: In this morning, i firstly hesitated about your answer, but after going gym, i correct your answer.$+1$

Comment: @NotaSalmonFish: Yes, briefly  the stars and bars formula used counts *k*-tuples of non-negative integers summing to *n*, and any *k*-tuple can be ordered in non-decreasing manner in just one way.

Answer (score 1):

It is said that the selected balls needs to be non-decreasing. It means $x_1 \leq x_2 \leq x_3 \leq ... \leq x_k$.

To make the solution more clear, lets assume that $k=4$ and $n=10$. So, we want to find the number of all solutions of $x_1 \leq x_2 \leq x_3 \leq x_4$ where $x_1$ is the first selected ball and the $x_4$ is the last selected ball.

Then,

- 1,1,3,9 is suitable
- 2,4,7,8 is suitable so on.

The question is how to find all those sequences, right ?

I will say that we can turn the sequence $x_1 \leq x_2 \leq x_3 \leq x_4$ into $y_1 < y_2 < y_3 < y_4$ by manipulating $x_1 \leq x_2 +1 \leq x_3 +2 \leq x_4 +3$

Then , because of we add $3$ at the end, our sample increased from $10$ to $13$

As a result, we showed that there is a **bijection** between the number of solutions of $x_1 \leq x_2 \leq x_3 \leq x_4$ where $n=10 $ and $k=4$ ,and $y_1 < y_2 < y_3 < y_4$ where $n=13 $ and $k=4$

So, for  $n=10 $ and $k=4$ : $$\frac{\binom{13}{4}}{10^4}$$

Then, the generalized form would be $$\frac{\binom{n+k-1}{k}}{n^k}$$

as @trueblueanil stated

Comment: This is so clever. Thank you

Comment: @nezamjazayeri you are welcome.. you can accept and upvote the answers to show that your question is completed.Otherwise, the community will continue to post answers if it is needed