# What is the expected number of $\min\{i \mid a_i\geq a_{i+1}\}$?

Tags: probability, recreational-mathematics, programming

I am solving a computer programming problem.
I wonder if an easy mathematical solution to the following problem exists or not.

> Suppose we throw a fair die sufficiently number of times.
> Let $a_i$ be the outcome of $i$-th roll.
> What is the expected number of $\min\{i \mid a_i\geq a_{i+1}\}$?

My attempt is here:
The probability of $\min\{i \mid a_i\geq a_{i+1}\}=1$ is $\frac{1}{6}\frac{6}{6}+\frac{1}{6}\frac{5}{6}+\frac{1}{6}\frac{4}{6}+\frac{1}{6}\frac{3}{6}+\frac{1}{6}\frac{2}{6}+\frac{1}{6}\frac{1}{6}$.

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: Hint: $\min \{i \mid a_i \geq a_{i + 1}\} < 6$ no matter what. For if the minimum is at least six, then we have $a_1 < a_2 < ... < a_6 < a_7$. This means that $a$ takes on at least 7 distinct values, which is impossible.

Comment: If $N$ is your value, and $M=a_N,$ then figure out how to compute $P(N=n,M=m).$ Then your expected value is: $$\sum_{n} n\sum_m P(N=n,M=m).$$ You already started doing this for $N=1.$

Comment: @MarkSaving Thank you very much for your comment.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Thank you very much for your comment.

Comment: I believe you can solve the problem building a Markov chain whose absorbing state is reached when a_i > a_i+1 ... each state corresponds to   the last obtained value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $X=\min\{i \mid a_i\geq a_{i+1}\}$

Then $P(X\ > i)=P(a_1 < a_2, a_2 < a_3 , ..., a_i < a_{i+1})$

Now, if we throw a $6-$faces die $k$ times, [there are $\binom{6}{k}$ possible strictly increasing sequences](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/658250/number-of-strictly-increasing-sequences-of-length-k-with-elements-from-1-2).

Hence the above probability is

$$P(X\ > i) = \frac{\binom{6}{i+1}}{6^{i+1}}$$

for $i =1,2 \cdots 5$. And [the expected value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expected_value#Basic_properties) is

$$\begin{align}
E[X] &= \sum_{i=0}^\infty P(X\ > i) 
\\ &= 1 + \sum_{i=1}^5 \frac{\binom{6}{i+1}}{6^{i+1}} \\ &=\sum_{k=0}^6 \binom{6}{k}{(1/6)^{k}} -1\\
&= \left(1 + \frac{1}{6}\right)^6-1\\
&=1.5216\cdots\end{align}$$

where we've used the [Binomial theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem).

Comment: leonbloy, Thank you very much for your answer.